# Trace the soap message in windows form application

Tags: c#, .net, soap, wsdl

I am developing a windows form application in visual studio 2010. Which is consuming soap webservice over https. I need to trace the messages to debug. I found out that Soap Extension is the solution for that. But, It can be used only for web applications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have u checked Service Trace Viewer Tool.
[here is the link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms732023%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

In your app config file use:

```
<system.diagnostics>
<trace autoflush="true" />
<sources>
        <source name="System.ServiceModel" 
                switchValue="Information, ActivityTracing"
                propagateActivity="true">
        <listeners>
           <add name="sdt" 
               type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener" 
               initializeData= "SdrConfigExample.e2e" />
        </listeners>
     </source>
</sources>
```